# JAX-RS ExceptionMapper throws MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException

Tags: jax-rs

Using JAX-RS, I have successfully implemented an ExceptionMapper for Exceptions that do not require a more sophisticated response than an HTTP status code, as follows.

```
@Provider 
public class ISBNNotFoundManager implements ExceptionMapper<ISBNNotFoundException>{

  @Override
  public Response toResponse(ISBNNotFoundException exception) {
      return Response.status(NOT_FOUND).build();
  }
}
```

This works as expected.

However, I want to respond with something more useful when bean validation fails. The follow code snippet results in a MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException.

```
@Provider
public class ConstraintViolationExceptionMapper implements 
                     ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {

  @Override
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException exception) {

      final Map<String, String> errorResponse =
        exception.getConstraintViolations()
        .stream()
        .collect(
          Collectors.toMap(o -> o.getPropertyPath().toString(), o -> o.getMessage()));


      return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(errorResponse).build();
    }

}
```

When a bean validation occurs the response includes the HTTP response code 500 and the root cause is given as follow:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException:
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, 
type=class java.util.HashMap, genericType=class java.util.HashMap.
```

What I have tried that didn't work:

- Wrapping the Map in a GenericEntity like so. The same result as above:

  new GenericEntity>(errorResponse) {}

What I tried the DID work:

- Wrapping the map in a custom POJO, DataIntegrityValidation, as follows:

  ```
  @XmlRootElement
  public class DataIntegrityValidation {

     private  Map<String, String> errorResponse = new HashMap<>();

     public Map<String, String> getErrorResponse() {
          return errorResponse;
     }

     public void setErrorResponse(Map<String, String> errorResponse) {
        this.errorResponse = errorResponse;
     }
  }
  ```

Then in the toResponse method I wrap the map in the DataIntegrityValidation POJO like so and add it to the response object.

```
    DataIntegrityValidation dataIntegrityValidation = 
       new DataIntegrityValidation();
         dataIntegrityValidation.setErrorResponse(errorResponse);

    return
      Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST)
      .entity(dataIntegrityValidation).build();
```

This gives the following JSON:

```
{
  "errorResponse": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "key": "saveBook.arg0.description",
        "value": "size must be between 100 and 2147483647"
      },
      {
        "key": "saveBook.arg0.published",
        "value": "must be in the past"
      },
      {
        "key": "saveBook.arg0.link",
        "value": "must match \"^(https?:\\/\\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w \\.-]*)*\\/?$\""
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can live with this but would really like to know why it cannot handle the Map even though it is wrapped in the Generic Entity.

All responses welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the marshalling failed for both Map and GenericEntity is because there is no JAXB definition associated with them. And when you wrapped the map in a POJO annotated with `@XmlRootElement`; it was able to marshal it correctly.

Comment: Makes perfect sense now you explain it to me. Cheers.